# windows xp & ie8 combination - div alignment issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, internet-explorer-8

there are two divs one below the other. In the top div, i load dynamic content on click of a link. In all browsers, the below div gets adjusted and moves down.

But in Windows XP+IE8 combination alone, the below div overlaps with the top div everytime when the dynamic content is loaded in the top div. But if we click anywhere in the page, the two divs gets adjusted correctly.

Have anyone come across any such issue?

Comment: Inconsistencies between IE versions used to be very common

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 8 will be 6 years old this year and Windows XP is even older; unless you have a requirement or data that proves a **significant** portion of your audience is using either I would stop supporting both with any type of dynamic content.

If you want and your current setup allows it, try serving your modern website to modern browers, and a stripped down basic page to outdated clients. Allowing them to browse the site and understand the content, but not benefit from the dynamic nature of your main site.